# Add new row in HTML using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, I have two text boxes namely Name,Age. I want to add the name and age entered in the text box to HTML table. When I use the below code it adds the row to the table for the first time and if I try to add more row, it modifies the last row added in the table. I'm passing the employee object here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        var myController = myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {

            $scope.employees = [
                { name: "Joe", age: "20" },
                { name: "Sam", age: "27" }
            ];

            $scope.addEmp = function (emp) {
                $scope.employees.push(emp);
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Age</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        Name<input id="Name" type="text" ng-model="emp.name"/>
        Age<input id="Age" type="text" ng-model="emp.age"/>
        <input type="button" ng-click="addEmp(emp)" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I pass the name and age separately as given below it works fine. Why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        var myController = myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {

            $scope.employees = [
                { name: "Joe", age: "20" },
                { name: "Sam", age: "27" }
            ];

            $scope.addEmp = function (name, age) {
                $scope.employees.push({name:name,age:age});
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Age</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        Name<input id="Name" type="text" ng-model="name"/>
        Age<input id="Age" type="text" ng-model="age"/>
        <input type="button" ng-click="addEmp(name,age)" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in first cash "emp" it's just black variable there no data 
but in second case there variable with data defined

Comment: which version of angularjs are you using ?
Both versions seem to work fine. [see demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oLpIKQnPNgzxf4Y2vKZ9?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is a JavaScript idiosyncrasy. When you push

> $scope.employees.push(emp);

into the array, that specific object is being added into the array(Objects and arrays are pushed by reference), what ever changes you do to the object will happen to the last element. When you push an object reference onto an array, you're just passing a reference, not copying the object. But when you use

> $scope.employees.push({name:name,age:age});

a new object is being created and is pushed into the array, ie, each time you call **addEmp()**, a new object is created and referred into the array.

Comment: If I replace $scope.employees.push(emp); to  $scope.employees.push(angular.copy(emp)); its working fine. So its passed by reference not by value. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, parameters of function are  given by reference when there are object. In your situation, when you give `emp`, you give a pointer to `emp` and so your function $scope.addEmp try to insert a second time the same object in your array whereas it is impossible in a array.

In your second example, you create a new object so everything is ok.

Comment: did you actually tested the code before giving explanations ? [see](http://plnkr.co/edit/oLpIKQnPNgzxf4Y2vKZ9?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Works in both the cases see [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hk3vu6qceMdh640x9McO?p=preview). In your code you are using the older version of angular. Use the link angular I mentioned in the below.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

also after adding the one row u need to empty the current object.

```
 $scope.addEmp = function (emp) {
            $scope.employees.push(emp);
           $scope.emp={};
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your firts sample you bind an object named emp in your scope.
This object reference is kept by angular.
So this first time, angular create the object emp with property name and age in scope. You add the object in your array.
But the second time the emp object is already created and you just update the object not create another.

In your second sample you create a new instance of emp each time you click on the button

Comment: did you actually tested the code before giving explanations ? [see](http://plnkr.co/edit/oLpIKQnPNgzxf4Y2vKZ9?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have just Edited Your Code and its working fine

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        var myController = myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
            /*
               here you define array and initlize objects too thats fine
            */
            $scope.employees = [
                { name: "Joe", age: "20" },
                { name: "Sam", age: "27" }
            ];

            $scope.addEmp = function (name, age) {
                $scope.list={};//create new object 


                $scope.list.name=name;
                $scope.list.age=age;

                $scope.employees.push($scope.list);
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Age</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        Name<input id="Name" type="text" ng-model="name"/>
        Age<input id="Age" type="text" ng-model="age"/>
        <input type="button" ng-click="addEmp(name,age)" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```